# how can I improve the response of BPS

Tags: wso2, bpel, ode

I have some WSO2 BPS processes that are stuck in retry. I have developed them in Studio with default settings and deployed them (ok, I see now that that generates quite some data). Opening an instance to inspect and retry it, now takes over 10 mins. How can I solve that and speed things up again?

Comment: what is the BPS version you are using. ?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.0.

Comment: what is the database you are using. Are you using internal h2 database ?

Comment: No we are on Oracle se1 on aws. The server is running on aws als well. I think this is partly because I have not limited the events in deploy.xml.

Comment: yupe. That could be the issue. It is not recommended to enable events in production systems.

Comment: no events at all? How can you then trace problems if something goes wrong?